# How to load my URL in place of inComing URL in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I want to load a separate URL in place of incoming URL in android. What i am doing is following :

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
if (url.contains("http://google.com")) {
url = url + "&ru=https://google.com/getTicket";
return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}
return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
}
```

But this is not loading the new URL. What should i do to load new URL??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with setting `setWebViewClient` with your `webview`.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        // Javascript inabled on webview
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//Load url in webview
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

webClient code

```
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            if (mProgressBar != null)
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("http://www.google.com")) {
                System.out.println(url);
                // Load your custom URL
                 mWebView.loadUrl(url + "&ru=https://google.com/getTicket");
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mWidgetWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if(url.contains("http://google.com")){
      view.loadUrl(url + "&ru=https://google.com/getTicket");
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Try this code, it should work.
when url contains 'http://google.com', load another url and return true.